# sshj/sftp unable to reach settlement even though BouncyCastle is loaded

Tags: java, sftp, bouncycastle

I am trying to upload some file to a server using custom sshj/sftp fat jar. However I am stuck on a problem where dependency is reporting that it is unable to reach a settlement.

USAGE:

```
java -jar ...
```

**NOTE**: This works on one server, but does not work on the other. Both servers have identical ciphers configured in *sshd_config*.

```
Bouncy Castle provider is available
net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: Unable to reach a settlement: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1] and [curve25519-sha256, curve25519-sha256@libssh.org, ecdh-sha2-nistp256, ecdh-sha2-nistp384, ecdh-sha2-nistp521, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256, diffie-hellman-group16-sha512, diffie-hellman-group18-sha512, diffie-hellman-group14-sha256, diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Proposal.firstMatch(Proposal.java:145)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Proposal.negotiate(Proposal.java:127)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger.gotKexInit(KeyExchanger.java:227)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger.handle(KeyExchanger.java:359)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.handle(TransportImpl.java:509)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:107)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Decoder.received(Decoder.java:175)
        at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:60)
```

I have added BouncyCastle as a provider:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
if (Security.getProvider("BC") == null){
   System.out.println("Bouncy Castle provider is NOT available");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Bouncy Castle provider is available");
}
```

This is excerpt from gradle build file:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task copyShadowLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.shadow
    into 'build/libs'
}

dependencies {
    implementation('commons-cli:commons-cli:1.5.0')
    implementation('com.jcraft:jzlib:1.1.3')
    implementation('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7')
    implementation('org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.7')
    implementation('com.hierynomus:sshj:0.16.0')
    shadow 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.67'
}

shadowJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'some_main_class'
    }
    archiveFileName = "${project.name}.jar"
}

shadowJar.dependsOn(copyShadowLibs)
```

I am out of ideas what to check - could be ssh version or something else entirely..

Comment: Not only the availability of bouncycastle itself is relevant, but also availability of the individual algorithms. One of each group written out in the error message about the failed settlement should be available. Or the building process doesn't care about your adding of Bouncycastle as provider, you could do it statically, like described here: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/wiki/Provider-Installation